# Drilling $scope to get a specific element in a complex auto complete DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

After trying to figure this out for a while It seem that i'm in a dead end situation, and thinking how easy it is in jQuery make me think about angular again, But maybe I am think about this is a wrong way.

Having this DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="ChildCategoriesController">
        <div style="float:right; width:362px; height:57px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black; position:relative; right:272px;">
            <input type="text" style="width:362px; height:57px; line-height:57px; font-family:Arial; font-size:24px;" ui-keyup="{'40':'keypressCallback11($event)'}" ng-model="jobChildCategoryModel.JobCategoryName" ng-change="change()" placeholder="Place Holder Example" />
            <div id="JobscCategories" style="width:362px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black; position:relative; right:1px; display:none; font-family:Arial; font-size:24px;">
                <div click enter leave ng-class="{'MouseOver':$first}" ng-repeat="cCategory in cCategories | filter:jobChildCategoryModel | orderBy:'JobCategoryName' | limitTo:7 | unique:'JobCategoryName'" ui-keyup="{'enter':'keypressCallback1($event)'}" id="cCategoryID_{{cCategory.JobCategoryID}}">{{cCategory.JobCategoryName}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; position:relative; right:352px; top:22px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial;"><a href="#">Show Jobs</a></div>
    </div>
```

I I can find where i am in the DOM when using the mouse with directives and every thing is working over there, But can't figure out how to do this with the key arrows. I can not bind the ui-keyup to the div elements (does not fire the event) and can not figure out how to move from the input to the auto complete divs with the arrows. weirder then that is that i can not find one full and good example to do this.

To be clear, the DOM is:

div --> 
       input
       div ---> 
               many div elements of categories
div

and i need to enable someone, after entering few letters in the input, to be able to use the arrows to move to the categories div and select one of them with the enter key or go back to the top. And also, if someone used the mouse to move and is on a specific element to be able to use the key from that point.... i even cant seem to find how to get the a specific element from the categories div block, as i don't know what is the index of the elements when i am in the controller.

Can any one answer this or send me to a good tutorial, every example is for a very basic DOM and couldn't find even one for this auto complete type of thing...weird, as there re hundreds of tutorial for jQuery for doing stuff like that.

Thank you

Comment: why not you are using jquery autocomplete with angular. Its pretty easy just bind autocomplete in a directive and put that directive on your input

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what you said. you told me to use jquery auto complete in the angular application? Isn't that the opposite way then the angular way to user selectors and DOM manipulation with jquery?

Comment: Yes but at the end both is javascript and jquery autocomplete just works fine if you bind it after dom population, which you can easily achieve by directive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
directive('autoComplete',function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(element, function () {
                    $(element).autocomplete(scope.$eval(attrs.autoComplete));
                })
            }
        };
    }).

 <input type="text" auto-complete="optionsForAutoComplete"/>
```

and define all your optionsForAutoComplete in your controller (which is actually usual autocomplete option you use in jquery). For Example:-

```
$scope.optionsForAutoComplete =   {
    minLength: 1,
    open: function () {
    },
    source: function (req, res) {
      res([{label: 'test', value: 'test', id: 101}, {label: 'test1', value: 'test1', id: 102}]);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
    }
};
```

Comment: In the example in jquery ui they are using a list, but i have an object and need all the object in the auto complete, will that still work? A list of object and not a list of strings? for every element in the list i need the name, the id and the parent id... and also need it to work in IE7, Yes we still develop for clients that use IE7, and I am not sure this will work

Comment: Yes you can use it and you can always use $scope to save your complex object since your optionsForAutoComplete is in your controller. otherwise jQuery autocomplete accept list of objects also.

Comment: As i can not find any other better answer "The angular way" I will go with your answer, It seem very logic to do it like this and not start killing my self to do it with my own auto complete, thank you

Comment: Yes We will obviously like to use angular autocomplete but it still not came so why not use what we have :)

Comment: Just one last thing if you can explain it to me. As i said, my data in Categoty name (will go to the label and the value i guess) and the categoryId (will go to the id) but where do i save the CategoryParentId if i don't have the model any more? i need them both when some one select something in the auto complete and i don't have the model any more from what i see in what you explained to me. when starting to combine jquery and angular it become very confusing to an Angular newbie like me. thank you

Comment: And i keep on getting this error after changing the data to return list of object of (label: name. value: name, id: number):     Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: I am sorry but i did exactly as you said and this is broken for some reason. I see that i have in the object that i enter into the res function in the source, that i have a list of objects with the data as you said but keep getting the error, please help...

Comment: @Erez can you give me sample code or create a fiddle for your code so I can see what you did wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39933/discussion-between-shreyance-jain-and-erez)